# Let $F$ be the set of infinite vectors $(a_0, a_1, ...)$ satisfying $a_i + a_{i+1} = a_{i+2}$ for all $i \geq 0$. Show that $F$ is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my thinking. To show it's a vector space, we need to show that $(F, +)$ is an abelian group, and the other general axioms that make something a vector space. However, the way the operation is defined doesn't make much sense to me. It's obviously closed under addition, and addition is obiviously commutative, but how can I show

$\begin{align*}
(a_i + a_{i+1}) + a_{i +2} = a_i + (a_{i+1} + a_{i+2})\\
a_{i+2} + a_{i +2} = ?
\end{align*}$

I guess the notation is really screwing with me here. 
Also, it has several follow up questions:

(a) What is a basis for F?

*Here I know that I need to find a set of vectors so that any element in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of these vectors.

(b) Find 2 linearly independent geometric series $v_i = ( 1, \lambda_i , \lambda_i^2,...)_{i\in \{1,2\}}$ in F.

*I have no clue how to approach this.

(c) Find the coordinates of the vector $(1,1,2,3,...)$ w.r.t. the basis $(v_1, v_2)$.

*This looks strangely reminiscent of the Fibonacci Sequence.

I apologize for the length of the question, but any help would be great.

Comment: Do we allow rational, real or complex values for the $a$s?

Comment: It does not distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you'll want to carefully distinguish between the addition in your underlying field and the addition in your vector space. While it is not entirely clear from your question, I presume that your vector space addition is defined pointwise.

So you have:
$(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots) + (b_0, b_1, b_2, \ldots) = (a_0 + b_0, a_1 + b_1, \ldots)$
Now you assume that both the $a_i$ and the $b_i$ satsify the criterion, and proceed to show that it applies to $(a_i + b_i)$ - which, as you've written boils down to $+$ being associative and commutative.

(Edited) For the second part, start with solving $1 + x = x^2$, and see where your solutions get you. To figure out how large the basis ought to be, think about how many degrees of freedom you have in principle to built an element of this vector space.

For the third part, yes, that is the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: There's no mistake: this is a standard exercise in deducing the Binet formula for the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Ah, of course. I somehow ended up looking at $1 + x = -x^2$ rather than $1 + x = x^2$.